# Put several Google Maps on page using Symfony and sfEasyGMapPlugin

Tags: google-maps, symfony1, plugins

I'm using Symfony 1.2.9 and sfEasyGMapPlugin 3.0.0

I need to put two gmaps on one page.

I've made custom ma name and DIV's id for each map. But I still can't make it work. Only second map is shown. The first one is not created.

Does anybody knows how to make them work using sfEasyGMapPlugin?

Answer (score 0):

One of the TODO items for sfEasyGMapPlugin is to "correct javascript files that suppose that the map's javascript object is called 'map'".

My guess is that, because of this problem, you can only refer to one map object per page. You could try finding where 'map' is hardcoded and replace it with $gMap. I haven't used the plugin myself, so I can't say for sure. I've only used the Google Maps API directly with Symfony. Hope that helps.